# location authorization alert showing up after app closes

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I created a singleton class to handle location authorization because I needed it for several views in my app. So I created the below Location.swift class.

NOTE: I have added correctly into Info.plist, and have looked at several other posts but none seem to address this (at least none I found)

```
protocol LocationServiceDelegate {
    func tracingLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation)
    func tracingLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError)
}

class Location:  NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var latitude: Double!
    var longitude: Double!
    var currentLocation : CLLocation!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var lastLocation: CLLocation?
    var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate?

    static let sharedInstance:Location = {
        let instance = Location()
        return instance
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager?.delegate = self

        guard let locationManagers = self.locationManager else {
            return
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            locationManagers.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        locationManagers.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManagers.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManagers.distanceFilter = 0.1

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        self.lastLocation = location
        updateLocation(currentLocation: location)

    }

    @nonobjc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .restricted:
            // restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services
            break
        case .denied:
            // user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
            break
        }
    }


    // Private function
    private func updateLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation){

        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }

        delegate.tracingLocation(currentLocation: currentLocation)
    }

    private func updateLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError) {

        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }

        delegate.tracingLocationDidFailWithError(error: error)
    }

    func startUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Starting Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        currentLocation = locationManager?.location
        Location.sharedInstance.latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        Location.sharedInstance.longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
        print(Location.sharedInstance.latitude, Location.sharedInstance.longitude)
        //        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Stop Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }


}
```

My app is crashing, and I think its because the location authorization is not set in the beginning. The funny thing is that the request alert which prompts the user to allow location services doesn't show up until you leave the app.

Once you close the app and accept the location services, the app works fine. So my question is, why isn't the alert showing up?

it is also interesting to note that this is only occurring through an actual device. In the simulator the alert pops up as expected when the initial view is loading.

my first view that is supposed to load and show data is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class CurrentWeatherVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTempLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherTypeLabel: UILabel!
    var currentWeather : CurrentWeather!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Location.sharedInstance.locationManager(manager: Location.sharedInstance.locationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus: .authorizedWhenInUse)
        currentWeather = CurrentWeather()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        Location.sharedInstance.startUpdatingLocation()
        currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails {
                   self.updateMainUI()
        }
    }

    func updateMainUI() {
        //Double value convterted to string for current temp.
        //Added the degree symbol here
        //For forecast it gets added in before saved into list so be aware of that. 
        currentTempLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.currentTemp)°"
        weatherTypeLabel.text = currentWeather.weatherType
        locationLabel.text = currentWeather.cityName
        weatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: currentWeather.weatherType)
    }

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't check the current authorisation status; just request when in use permission each time. iOS will only prompt the user once.

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah I tried just requesting it as well, and the same issue persists. Alert wont pop up until i click home button and leave app. In simulator alert shows up correctly, which is odd. Maybe It has someting to do with view not loading in main view?

Comment: It sounds like you are blocking the main thread or updating the UI from a background thread. Your are calling the delegate method from your view controller, which you should not do. Only the `CLLocationManager` should call its delegate functions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `downloadWeatherDetails`s implementation uses a `dataTask` or one of the other `NSURLSession` methods that run in background.

Make sure to call UI stuff only on the `mainQueue`:

```
// ...
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.updateMainUI()
}
// ...
```